# When I try "grant create session to user" in Oracle through SQL*Plus I get output "2"

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

When i try to "**grant create session to user**" through SQL*Plusin the terminal window I get output "**2**"
Instead of "Access granted" I am also able to write after the output and if I do and press enter number 3 appears and this repeats like that untill I press enter without writing anything after the number, the setting I am trying to set doesn't get set for the user either.
When i search on the web I can't find anyone describing this problem, and it looks like it should have worked...
What am I doing wrong?
Please help :(

Comment: Put a `;` after the `grant create session to user`. 2, 3, 4, ... are line numbers.

Comment: Thank you, this worked, I feel really stupid now...

Comment: no need to feel stupid, we all start somewhere